# Clion compiler error using Xcode compiler

Tags: c++, xcode, clion

My Xcode version is 7.2.1, I don't know why my gcc compiler couldn't work neither in Clion nor Xcode.
I have tried in terminal, It's ok.
but, in clion, when I wanted to build the project, it turned out :

```
Error:Configuration MinSizeRel
The C compiler "/Applications/Xcode 7.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc" is not able to compile a simple test program.
It fails with the following output:
 Change Dir: /Users/benji/Library/Caches/CLion12/cmake/generated/39d888a/39d888a/MinSizeRel/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_d3d16/fast"
/Applications/Xcode 7.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_d3d16.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_d3d16.dir/build
make: /Applications/Xcode: No such file or directory
make: *** [cmTC_d3d16/fast] Error 1
CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: /Users/benji >gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode 7.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode 7.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.4.0
Thread model: posix
➜ /Users/benji >whereis gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
➜ /Users/benji >whereis make
/usr/bin/make
➜ /Users/benji >

Comment: I just tried, it also couldn't work out in terminal.

Comment: Looks like CMake isn't too happy about working with paths with spaces in them. Such paths are usually avoided. Remove the space from the name of your XCode.